# ¿Como creo una superclase con 3 campos, y dos subclases hereden los atributos de la superclase?

Tags: java

en este ejemplo se supone que en la subclase avión heredara atributos que tiene vehiculo pero marca este error

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
> (default-cli) on project sem1: Command execution failed.: Process
> exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging

```
public class Avion extends Vehiculo{

}

public class Vehiculo  {

    private String destino;
    private int cantidad;
    private double precio;

    public void calcularPrecio(double pARG, double pBol, double pECU) {
        switch (destino) {
            case "Argentina":
                precio = pARG;
                break;
            case "Bolivia":
                precio = pBol;
                break;
            case "Ecuador":
                precio = pECU;
                break;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Vehiculo v=new Vehiculo();
        Omnibus o = new Omnibus();
        o.calcularPrecio(320, 290, 270);
        System.out.println("Ingresar pais");
        
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Deberias agregar el error completo para saber que parte de tu codigo falla

Comment: Los atributos con el modificador de acceso `private` NUNCA se heredan. Prueba declararlos `protected` o `public`. De cualquier manera, tus relaciones de herencia, tus métodos, y hasta el código que expones carecen de sentido. Adjunta por favor el mensaje de error y mejora tu código ¿Qué sentido tiene un campo de `cantidad` y `destino` en `Vehiculo`? ¡Ninguno!

Comment: Por favor especifica que es lo que quieres, si quieres saber como heredar y tener acceso a los atributos de la super clase o si quieres solucionar el error que describes.